# UIImagePickerController throws ERROR: 185: Error creating aggregate audio device: 'what' when trying to select video

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

when i try to use UIImagePickerController to select a video from camera roll in the iOS-Simulator of XCode 5, i get the aforementioned error. this is the output:

```
2013-11-02 21:28:44.788 Imagepicker[89146:1403] 21:28:44.788 ERROR:     185: Error creating aggregate audio device: 'what'
2013-11-02 21:28:44.788 Imagepicker[89146:1403] 21:28:44.788 WARNING:   219: The input device is 0x32; 'AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,1:2'
2013-11-02 21:28:44.789 Imagepicker[89146:1403] 21:28:44.789 WARNING:   223: The output device is 0x28; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'
2013-11-02 21:28:44.790 Imagepicker[89146:1403] 21:28:44.790 ERROR:     398: error 'what'
2013-11-02 21:28:44.791 Imagepicker[89146:a0b] 21:28:44.791 ERROR:     398: error -66680
2013-11-02 21:28:44.791 Imagepicker[89146:a0b] 21:28:44.791 ERROR:     398: error -66680
2013-11-02 21:28:44.792 Imagepicker[89146:a0b] 21:28:44.792 ERROR:     398: error -66680
2013-11-02 21:28:44.792 Imagepicker[89146:a0b] 21:28:44.792 ERROR:     398: error -66680
```

my code is:

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.mediaTypes =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie,kUTTypeVideo,kUTTypeImage, nil];
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

the image picker shows up, shows a preview with cancel, play and choose button and a dialog that says "The operation could not be completed". after pressing "OK" (the only button), the preview freezes.

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

never gets called. it all works fine with images.

Comment: I had the same error on the simulator today. Running the code on the device worked perfectly - does your code work on the device? I suspect it's something to do with video format issues when importing to simulator.

Comment: i cannot yet put software on the device, so i cannot tell. is this a known issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any references to it being a known issue sorry.

Comment: thank you for your time, i am quite relieved to know it will work on the device.

Comment: I am facing same issue on iPhone device and couldn't find any error or error code in debug console, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem with the latest toolchain, but the following fixed it for me;

1. On the simulator Hardware menu, select TV Out->640x480.
2. Attempt to launch your app from Xcode, it may fail with a springboard error.
3. On the simulator Hardware menu, select TV Out->Disabled.

After that the ImagePickerController should now work as expected.

Comment: I received the "ERROR: 185" message when attempting to play an <audio> tag within a UIWebView. However, this solution solved my problem as well.

Comment: Best Answer. I wonder though -- how did you manage to find a workaround. 
Just curious -- I would appreciate if you could share

Comment: Holy crap, it does work. How in hell did you find that workaround? Trial and error? Unbelievable, if I could up-vote your answer multiple times I would. Cheers!

Comment: doesn't work for me. it still show "The operation could not be completed" alert. :(

Answer (score 9):

"iOS simulator" -> "Reset content and settigs..." 
solved similar problem in my case.

Comment: +1 I got it on HLS playback, and "Reset content and settigs..." solved it. 10x

Answer (score 2):

I faced same error when I tried to run an audio file on simulator. The strange cause I discovered was  connection of my headphones to mac when simulator was running. It couldn't detect new state of audio probably, so this exception was raised. Restarting simulator solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Your Simulator
IOS Simulator->Reset Content and Settings..